# member template variable specializing

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-specialization, template-variables

A class can contain a member template variable which must be static:

```
class B
{   
    public:
        template <typename X>
            static X var;

        B() { std::cout << "Create B " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

        template <typename T>
        void Print() { std::cout << "Value is " << var<T> << std::endl; }
};
```

It must as all static members be declared outside the class scope:

The following compiles and works as expected:

```
 template<typename T> T B::var=9; // makes only sense for int,float,double...
```

But how to specialize such a var like the following non working code ( error messages with gcc 6.1):

```
template <> double B::var<double>=1.123;
```

Fails with:

```
main.cpp:49:23: error: parse error in template argument list
 template <> double B::var<double>= 1.123;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:49:23: error: template argument 1 is invalid
main.cpp:49:23: error: template-id 'var<<expression error> >' for 'B::var' does not match any template declaration
main.cpp:38:22: note: candidate is: template<class X> T B::var<T>
             static X var;
```

```
template <> double B::var=1.123;
```

Fails with

```
   template <> double B::var=1.123;
                       ^~~
main.cpp:38:22: note: does not match member template declaration here
             static X var;
```

What is the correct syntax here?

Comment: Can you please include the actual error you get?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Done ;)

Comment: Well those are less than helpful.  I was hoping there would be something in there to make the title more searchable but alas, the compiler is not helping here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose you should add a space

```
template <> double B::var<double> = 1.123;
                                 ^ here
```

Otherwise (if I'm not wrong) `>=1.123` is confused with "equal or greather than 1.123"

Comment: That is... amazingly silly (the cause, not the answer).

Comment: I've understand where is the problem because I've done the same error two hours ago :(

Comment: An example of how poor code formatting actually can lead to bugs. At least in this case the compiler caught it.

Comment: Verily, one of the runner-ups behind the [most-vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/most-vexing-parse)...

Comment: @einpoklum - I'm bad in labelling but... yes, something similar